# Ruby gem for text comparison

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am looking for a gem that can compare two strings (in this case paragraphs of text) and be able to gauge the likelihood that they are similar in content (with perhaps only a few words rearranged, changed). I believe that SO uses something similar when users submit questions.

Comment: You could always just compare word counts. Anything more than that would be computer comprehension, and your getting yourself far above what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd probably use something like Diff::LCS:

```
>> require "diff/lcs"
>> seq1 = "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consequtor".split(" ")
>> seq2 = "lorem ipsum dolor amet sit consequtor".split(" ")
1.9.3-p194 :010 > Diff::LCS.diff(seq1, seq2).length
 => 2
```

It uses the [longest common subsequence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) algorithm (the method for using LCS to get a diff is described on [the wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem#Print_the_diff)).

Comment: Thank you Yehuda, didn't know you hung around on SO. My theoretical CS is getting rustier the more I dig myself into Rails and the faster moving technologies, indeed I hardly find myself building complex algorithms from the ground up anymore...